# How to search for an ip hosting a socket in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am currently using the socket library in python to send basic text from one computer to another on the same local network.

My problem is that due to me using different computers on multiple occasions the iPv4 which the client connects to changes each time .

Line 4 of the client code : `client.connect(("172.16.0.34",8888))`

This introduces a difficulty as I cant change the ip in the client code very easily.

**My Question:**

Is there possibly a way that the client can "scan" the network to see what ip is hosting a socket and obtain that ip to connect to them, allowing me to use any computer and have it still functioning?

**Here is my code:**

**Client:**

```
import socket
client = socket.socket()
try:
    client.connect(("172.16.0.34",8888))
except:
    print("Server not connected")
else:
    print("Connect to server: ","localhost")
while True:
    print("[Waiting for response...]")
    print(client.recv(1024))
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            msg = str(input("Enter your message to send: "))
        except:
            print("Invalid input format")
        else:
            valid = True
    to_send = msg.encode("UTF-8")
    client.send(to_send)
```

**Server:**

```
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket created")
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8888
print(host)
try:
    server.bind((host,port))
except:
    print("Bind failed")
else:
    print("Bind successful")
server.listen(5)
clientsocket = None
while True:
    if clientsocket == None:
        print("[Waiting for connection..]")
        (clientsocket, address) = server.accept()
        print("Client accepted from", address)
    else:
        print("[Waiting for response...]")
        print(clientsocket.recv(1024))
        valid = False
        while not valid:
            try:
                msg = str(input("Enter your message to send: "))
            except:
                print("Invalid input format")
            else:
                valid = True
        clientsocket.send(msg.encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: If you try to connect to the local host, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is the so called *loopback* address which is always bound to the local machine. It is commonly used for tests and early development

Comment: @SergeBallesta just to confirm this would be the ip the client connects to, correct?